# How to power my datalogger?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, batteries

I am building GPS datalogger. It will consist of [Arduino Pro Mini](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardProMini) 3.3V, GPS module - [GY-GPS6MV2 (GPS Ublox NEO-6M)](http://www.amateurradio.com/cheap-gps-module/) (bypassing 3.3V  regulator) or [Skylab SKM53 (MT3329)](http://file01.up71.com/File/CorpDownFile/2012/08/18/0_skylab_20120818151614.pdf). Data will be written to SPI Flash [W25Q64FVSIG](http://www.winbond.com/NR/rdonlyres/A88DEF07-8303-4617-BAE6-B8A365057DC8/0/W25Q64CV.pdf) and later read via USB with [FT232RL FTDI](http://www.ebay.com/itm/181438947135?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) 3.3V.

I am looking for a power supply solution having following criteria:

- powering with multiple standard rechargable NiMH 1.2V AA batteries
- effective power supply capable of higher current (my guess is 150mA but I am not 100% sure about this)
- automatic circuit cutoff on voltage drop below minimum recommended for the circuit and also for NiMH batteries to not to overdischarge and damage them
- notification of low battery power (eg. by bliking LED) before cutoff

So far I was trying to use [DC-DC step-up voltage convertor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/231083181020?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) with together 4 batteries - two pairs of serially connected baterries finally connected in parallel so they can provide doulbe current, [but the circuit seems to require more current](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121813/voltage-decreases-on-higher-current/121825). Maybe I should probably consider rather some more powerful DC-DC step-down voltage convertor.

I've asked about [automatic circuit cutoff and notification of low battery power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/lvd-solution-with-low-power-indication) already but I would appreciate to have a complete solution combined with all four requirements.

I will appreciate a solution to this complex yet common problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a microcontroller then you can implement some of what you're looking for just in firmware. Namely, the automatic low voltage cut-out is known as brown-out and is something you can set fuses for on the AVR chip itself in which a RESET event will be triggered. However, you might look into a [latching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoMdH.jpg) circuit that could be switched off when a RESET occurs. See page 47 in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2545.pdf).

The blinking LED is about the simplest program you can write. Once low-voltage is detected, either through brown-out or ADC, drive an LED with PWM and a timer if you want it to blink. If you simply want an indicator then just drive the LED high and forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick to get under voltage lockout (i.e. turn the system off when the battery voltage gets too low) is to buy a voltage regulator with an "enable" or "~shutdown" pin that has a precise threshold. Then you just form a divider off of your battery stack to set the threshold. You will want an enable pin that has some hysteresis for this. This is a feature of many Linear Technology voltage regulators.